# Dataframe variable names in R

Tags: r

Very basic question - but something I haven't seen before. My variable names have 'subnames' beneath them (see image link below).

[variable names and subnames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6vzi.png)

When I call colnames - i just get the main name:

```
colnames(df) 

"Age"              "Gender"           "AgeGenderQuota"   "AgeGenStateQuota"
"Q1_1"             "Q2_1"             "Q3_1"
```

Any ideas on how i call the subnames in the pic above?

Comment: Suggest `str(df)` to see what the structure of `df` looks like first.

Comment: To insert a picture into your question you can just copy it and press Ctrl + V (or whatever is your OS shortcut) in the editor.

Comment: Welcome to SO Henry.  What package/code are you using to load the data?  I think both `hmisc` and `haven` can add the extra attributes. We need to know how to the code was created to help.  If possible please share your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are stored as a column attribute called *label*. You can access them with the function `attr()`:

An example:

```
df <- data.frame(
  x = structure(10, label = 'This is x'), 
  y = structure(3, label = 'and this is our y')
)

attr(df$x, 'label')
# [1] "This is x"
```

And modify:

```
attr(df$x, 'label') <- 'This is x which is our first column'
```

And to get all at once:

```
sapply(df, attr, 'label')
#                                     x                                     y 
# "This is x which is our first column"                   "and this is our y"
```

To see all the attributes you can use the function `attributes()`:

```
attributes(df$x)
# $label
# [1] "This is x"
```

Answer (score 1):

The subnames that you're referencing are the column labels.

To retrieve all the labels, you can use:

```
library(tidyverse)
colnames(df) %>%
  map(~attr(df[[.x]], "label")) %>%
  flatten()
```

where `attr()` returns a *named* `character` vector.

This code loops `attr()` over all the columns and returns a *named* `list` of column labels.

**Alternate Solution**

If you want an easy one liner to retrieve the column labels as a `vector`, check out a tidyverse-approved package `sjlabelled`

```
library(sjlabelled)
labels <- get_label(df)
```